# Why am I getting this bundle error on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

This is the error on rails when I try running bundle command

```
bundle exec rake -P
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup
```

This is my Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '5.1.6'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.12'
gem 'faker',                   '1.7.3'
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.2.2'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.7.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',                    '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',                '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.7.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.14.1'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',  '0.20.0'
  gem 'fog', '1.42'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I have tried running "git push heroku master" and it suggested running command "bundle exec rake -p" which then gave me the first error at the top.

This is my first time working with Ruby on rails so I'm confused about the errors and especially working with heroku.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795787/rails-help-with-rake-aborted-error and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943969/bundle-update-rake-not-fixing-my-you-have-already-activated-rake-error

Comment: You are trying to use bootsnap, but I don't see that added to your Gemfile. Can you also post the stack trace on the rake to see which file is trying to require bootsnap/setup